# Populate list from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hoping this is a quick fix but can't quite get my head around this (I am a newbie), I have this bit of code in C# that sends data up to Stripe checkout, this works great, question is, how can I populate the `SessionLineItemOptions` dynamically from a database?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "";

    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        SuccessUrl = "http://localhost:51835/secure/success.aspx?id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
        CancelUrl = "http://localhost:51835/secure/cancel.aspx",
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>{
            "card",
          },
        Mode = "payment",

        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> {
    //getDataFromDataBase().ToList();
            new SessionLineItemOptions{
            Name = "Product 1",
            Amount = 4999,
            Currency = "gbp",
            Quantity = 1
        },
            new SessionLineItemOptions{
            Name = "Product 2",
            Amount = 12550,
            Currency = "gbp",
            Quantity = 1
        },
            new SessionLineItemOptions{
            Name = "Product 3",
            Amount = 9999,
            Currency = "gbp",
            Quantity = 1
        },
        },
    };

    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Create(options);
    sessionId = session.Id;
}
```

I tried this to get the product information back out but this is where I have gotten stuck, help is greatly appreciated.

```
public List<string> getDataFromDataBase()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionStringHere"))
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable tap = new DataTable();
        new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'ABCDEFG'", con).Fill(tap);
        result = tap.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("name")).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better if you spend a little of your time to learn simple ORM like Dapper and all that pain in converting datatable rows to your objects will go away. You can find it here https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper